# How can I load the docker images before the service starts?

Tags: vagrant, docker, coreos

I spend some time with the Vagrant & CoreOS and Docker, There's so much to learn...

I work in a development environment and constantly **UP** and **DESTROY** operation So I do not want to **download the docker images every time**... It takes too much time, images are very heavy.

Well, I pull the images what I use most frequently and save them.

```
core@core-01 ~ $ docker save ubuntu:latest > /home/core/share/ubuntu.tar
core@core-01 ~ $ docker save mysql > /home/core/share/mysql.tar
core@core-01 ~ $ docker save wordpress:latest > /home/core/share/wordpress.tar
```

I'm loading them again if required.

```
core@core-03 ~ $ docker load -i=/home/core/share/wordpress.tar
core@core-04 ~ $ docker load -i=/home/core/share/mysql.tar
```

#### so far everything is OK.

But I'm having problems when I try to build the cluster.

I have two simple service database and web

database.1.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Run database_1
After=docker.service
Requires=docker.service

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name database_1   -e "MYSQL_DATABASE=demo" -e "MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password" -p 3306:3306 mysql
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker kill database_1
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

web.1.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Run web_1
After=database.1.service
Requires=database.1.service

[Service]
Restart=always
RestartSec=10s
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm
ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker run --rm --name web_1  --link database_1:database_1 -e "DB_USER=root" -e "DB_PASSWORD=password" -p 80:80 wordpress
ExecStartPost=/usr/bin/docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm
ExecStop=/usr/bin/docker kill web_1
ExecStopPost=/usr/bin/docker ps -a -q | xargs docker rm

[Install]
WantedBy=local.target
```

How do I load mysql image (/home/core/share/mysql.tar) before the service start.
if the service starts then download the images again.

```
$ fleetctl start database.1.service
$ fleetctl start web.1.service
```

Can I Load the images as follows?

```
ExecStartPre=/usr/bin/docker load -i=/home/core/share/mysql.tar
```

#### The question is;

How do I create a development environment to work **without an internet connection**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be over-complicating things. You should not have to explicitly ask for an image to be saved and/or reused.

According to the CoreOS documentation

> [The overlay filesystem works similar to git: our image now builds off of the ubuntu base and adds another layer with Apache on top. **These layers get cached separately so that you won't have to pull down the ubuntu base more than once**.](https://coreos.com/docs/launching-containers/building/getting-started-with-docker/)

While this still requires an internet connection for the initial image download, subsequent launches of the container should reuse the cached image.

If you require more control, you might want to look into maintaining a private Docker registry within your CoreOS cluster. The best way I've found to do this is using [Deis](http://deis.io), which comes with a load of goodies, including a cluster-wide fault-tolerant file-system and a private Docker registry as standard.